# Why does the Maven Flyway Plugin Fail to Migrate My Hsqldb database?

Tags: maven, hsqldb, flyway

I am having trouble initializing and migrating a HSQLDB database using flyway and the maven plugin.

I have this block of XML in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${project.build.directory}/db/margarita;shutdown=true</url>
        <user>develop</user>
        <password></password>
        <schemas>margarita</schemas>
        <table>schema_history</table>
        <initialVersion>118</initialVersion>
        <initialDescription>Base Migration</initialDescription>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When I run this command:

```
mvn flyway:migrate
```

I get this error message:

```
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:1.5:migrate (default-cli) @ Margarita ---
[INFO] Database closed
[INFO] Hsql does not support locking. No concurrent migration supported.
[INFO] Database closed
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE MARGARITA.schema_history (
version VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR(100),
type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
script VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
checksum INT,
installed_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
installed_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
execution_time INT,
state VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
current_version BIT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT MARGARITA.schema_history_script_unique UNIQUE (script)
)
[ERROR] Caused by org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: MARGARITA
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.550s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 20 21:54:06 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:1.5:migrate (default-cli) on project Margarita: Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE MARGARITA.schema_history (
[ERROR] version VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
[ERROR] description VARCHAR(100),
[ERROR] type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] script VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] checksum INT,
[ERROR] installed_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] installed_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
[ERROR] execution_time INT,
[ERROR] state VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] current_version BIT NOT NULL,
[ERROR] CONSTRAINT MARGARITA.schema_history_script_unique UNIQUE (script)
[ERROR] ): StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [CREATE TABLE MARGARITA.schema_history (
[ERROR] version VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
[ERROR] description VARCHAR(100),
[ERROR] type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] script VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] checksum INT,
[ERROR] installed_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] installed_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
[ERROR] execution_time INT,
[ERROR] state VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] current_version BIT NOT NULL,
[ERROR] CONSTRAINT MARGARITA.schema_history_script_unique UNIQUE (script)
[ERROR] )]; SQL state [3F000]; error code [-4850]; invalid schema name: MARGARITA; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: MARGARITA
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Is this not a supported process? I thought hsqldb would automatically create the referenced schema, so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have an error in your SQL script :

`Caused by org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: MARGARITA`

Try updating you SQL script by removing the schema name from the CREATE TABLE clause. Example :

```
CREATE TABLE schema_history (
version VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR(100),
...
```

Comment: Or execute `CREATE SCHEMA MARGARITA AUTHORIZATION DBA` before the `CREATE TABLE MARGARITA.schema_history(...` statement.

Comment: I think fredt's solution is the right one in this case, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the next command: `mvn flyway:clean flyway:init flyway:migrate`
it should work

And take a look here: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/